# Формирование XML из массива данных

Tags: php, xml

Задача сформировать файл XML из JSON данных.
Вручную получается собрать такой файл, а вот как из массива не могу понять.

Формат XML файла нужен такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kaspi_catalog date="string"
              xmlns="kaspiShopping"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="kaspiShopping http://kaspi.kz/kaspishopping.xsd">
   <company>CompanyName</company>
    <merchantid>CompanyID</merchantid>
    <offers>
        <offer sku="232130213">
            <model>iphone 5s white 32gb</model>
            <brand>Apple</brand>
            <availabilities>
                <availability available="yes" storeId="myFavoritePickupPoint1"/>
                <availability available="yes" storeId="myFavoritePickupPoint2"/>
            </availabilities>
            <price>6418</price>
        </offer>
        <offer sku="232130223">
            <model>iphone 6s white 32gb</model>
            <brand>Apple</brand>
            <availabilities>
                <availability available="yes" storeId="myFavoritePickupPoint1"/>
                <availability available="yes" storeId="myFavoritePickupPoint2"/>
            </availabilities>
            <cityprices>
            <cityprice cityId="750000000">193000</cityprice>
            <cityprice cityId="710000000">195000</cityprice>
            </cityprices>
        </offer>
    </offers>
</kaspi_catalog>
```

Мой код ручного формирования :

```
<?php
$simplexml= new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <kaspi_catalog/>');
$simplexml->addAttribute('xmlns:date', 'string');
$simplexml->addAttribute('xmlns:xmlns', 'kaspiShopping');
$simplexml->addAttribute('xmlns:xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$simplexml->addAttribute('xmlns:xsi:schemaLocation', 'kaspiShopping http://kaspi.kz/kaspishopping.xsd');
$simplexml->addChild("company", "CompanyName");
$simplexml->addChild("merchantid", "CompanyID");

$offers = $simplexml->addChild('offers');
$offer = $offers->addChild('offer');
$offer->addAttribute('offer:sku', '232130213');
$offer->addChild("model", "iphone 5s white 32gb");
$offer->addChild("brand", "Apple");
$availabilities = $offer->addChild("availabilities");
$availabilities->addChild("availabilities");

file_put_contents('price_list.xml', $simplexml->asXML());

?>
```

Исходный JSON выглядит так:

```
"balanceArray": [
        {
            "id": "7",
            "productId": "36",
            "productCode1c": "",
            "code": "759fd581d807dced6a4995c33a395788",
            "amount": "1.000",
            "amountavaillable": 1,
            "currency": "KZT",
            "currencyrate": "421.000",
            "price": "0.0000",
            "productname": "Janome Grape 2016 белый-зеленый",
            "serial": "19123879",
            "storageName": "Основной ALA"
        },
```

Comment: А что лежит в массиве?

Comment: Начните с одного значения потом попрет

Comment: Yessey, вы можете использовать MS SQL Server для своей задачи?

Comment: @AzizUmarov что массиве указал выше в вопросе.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Я думал над этим, можно попробовать через БД. Вы думаете так будет проще ?

Comment: @Yessey, Я думаю, что да. SQL Server поддерживает как JSON, так и XML

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky поддерживать-то поддерживает, но задача преобразовать один массив в совершенно другой по структуре. Гелендваген тоже хорошо поддерживает покосившийся деревенский дом где-нибудь на просторах урюпинских, а смысл?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($json as $key => $val) {
  $offer->addChild($key, $val);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот как это сделать.

Непонятно, как сопоставить JSON с элементами XML, потому что они имеют разные имена. Но вы сможете адаптировать решение к тому, что вам нужно.

Это работает в SQL Server 2016 и более поздних версиях.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @json_text NVARCHAR(MAX) =
N'{
    "balanceArray": [
        {
            "id": "7",
            "productId": "36",
            "productCode1c": "",
            "code": "759fd581d807dced6a4995c33a395788",
            "amount": "1.000",
            "amountavaillable": 1,
            "currency": "KZT",
            "currencyrate": "421.000",
            "price": "1.0000",
            "productname": "Janome Grape 2016 белый-зеленый",
            "serial": "19123879",
            "storageName": "Основной ALA"
        },
        {
            "id": "17",
            "productId": "136",
            "productCode1c": "",
            "code": "759fd581d807dced6a4995c33a395788",
            "amount": "1.000",
            "amountavaillable": 1,
            "currency": "KZT",
            "currencyrate": "421.000",
            "price": "18.0000",
            "productname": "Janome Grape 2016 белый",
            "serial": "19123770",
            "storageName": "Основной ALA"
        }
    ]
}';

DECLARE @today DATE = GETDATE()
    , @comanyName NVARCHAR(100) = 'Famous Company Name'
    , @CompanyID NVARCHAR(20) = 'ABZ-770';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'kaspiShopping'
          , 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
SELECT (
SELECT *
   FROM OPENJSON(@json_text, '$.balanceArray')
    WITH (
      id int '$.id',
      productId int '$.productId',
      serial NVARCHAR(20) '$.serial',
      productname NVARCHAR(50) '$.productname',
      currencyrate DECIMAL(6,3) '$.currencyrate',
      price DECIMAL(10,4) '$.price'
   )
FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('<kaspi_catalog date="{sql:variable("@today")}" xmlns="kaspiShopping"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="kaspiShopping http://kaspi.kz/kaspishopping.xsd">
    <company>{sql:variable("@comanyName")}</company>
    <merchantid>{sql:variable("@CompanyID")}</merchantid>
    <offers>
    {
        for $x in /root/r
        return <offer sku="{data($x/serial)}">
            <model>{data($x/productname)}</model>
            <brand>???</brand>
            <availabilities>
                <availability available="yes" storeId="myFavoritePickupPoint1"/>
                <availability available="yes" storeId="myFavoritePickupPoint2"/>
            </availabilities>
            <price>{data($x/price)}</price>
        </offer>
    }
    </offers>
</kaspi_catalog>
');
```

**Результат**

```
<kaspi_catalog xmlns="kaspiShopping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" date="2021-02-06" xsi:schemaLocation="kaspiShopping http://kaspi.kz/kaspishopping.xsd">
  <company>Famous Company Name</company>
  <merchantid>ABZ-770</merchantid>
  <offers>
    <offer sku="19123879">
      <model>Janome Grape 2016 белый-зеленый</model>
      <brand>???</brand>
      <availabilities>
        <availability available="yes" storeId="myFavoritePickupPoint1" />
        <availability available="yes" storeId="myFavoritePickupPoint2" />
      </availabilities>
      <price>1.0000</price>
    </offer>
    <offer sku="19123770">
      <model>Janome Grape 2016 белый</model>
      <brand>???</brand>
      <availabilities>
        <availability available="yes" storeId="myFavoritePickupPoint1" />
        <availability available="yes" storeId="myFavoritePickupPoint2" />
      </availabilities>
      <price>18.0000</price>
    </offer>
  </offers>
</kaspi_catalog>
```

Comment: Ну это совсем из пушки по воробьям

Comment: Одно-единственное выражение SQL - и задача решена.

Comment: дада, одно-единственное выражение на 5 экранов. плюс слона-то (обращение к маргинальной СУБД) мы и не заметили